# Store percentage of a column based on grouping

Tags: mysql

I want to store the percentage value for a given column but based on grouping of two other fields:

```
Select FieldA,FieldB,
       Value/(Select sum(Value) from Table1  group by FieldA,FieldB) 
from Table1
```

My goal once I get this right is to turn it into an Update of course but right now I am getting

*"[Err] 1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row"*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a correlated subquery for this:

```
Select FieldA, FieldB, Value / (Select sum(Value) 
                                from Table1  as t2
                                where t2.FieldA = t1.FieldA AND
                                      t2.FieldB = t1.FieldB) 
from Table1 as t1
```

The problem with your query is that the subquery returns multiple values: one for each `FieldA, FieldB` group, whereas a *scalar* value is needed in order to perform division. Using correlation a scalar value is returned by the subquery: the sum of `Value` that corresponds to the current `FieldA, FieldB` values.